# How do I Scroll a Page within an Iframe in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I am trying to scroll a page within an iframe using javaScript - window.scrollTo().
I have studied and tried other scenarios on stackOverflow and elsewhere and still cannot get the page to scroll to the bottom right.
The example included is a simplified version of what I am trying to achieve. No matter what options I try I cannot get this to scroll. There are scroll bars within the iframe, as well as scroll bars on the containing page.
I have no problems scrolling pages and frames in Edge and Chrome. My problem is only with Safari.

My code & resources:

Index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <!-- 
      Demo using scrollTo in Safari 
    -->
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>ScrollTo Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body id="sBody">
    <button id="sButton" type="button"> scroll page 1 </button><br>
      <iframe id="page1" 
      src = "./page1.html"
      frameborder="0" 
      marginheight="0" 
      marginwidth="0"
      width="auto"
      height="auto">
    </iframe>
    
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

index.css:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
      
  iframe {
    display: block; 
    border: none; 
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
```

index.js:

```
function scroll() {

    window.scrollTo(300,100);
    console.log("scrolled to...")
}

sButton.addEventListener("click", scroll);
```

page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <!-- 
      Demo using scrollTo in Safari 
    -->
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>ScrollTo Demo - page 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Demonstrates scrolling a page</h2>
    <img src="./photo.jpeg" alt="Roma Italia">
  </body>
</html>
```

[photo.jpg included in page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwpBj.jpg)

I have tried using scrollTo() on the window, body, iframe without success.
I have read that Safari sizes the frame to suit its contents but I can still see scroll bars inside the frame.